# Using an array as Subscript Indice to access elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I'd like to create an array from elements in an 3D-matrix using z-coordinates stored in an another array.
The simplest way would be:

```
X=2;
Y=3;
lastZ=10000000
for i=1:lastZ
    new_array=matrix(X,Y,Z(i));
end
```

But I'm looking for a "vectorized" way using only matrices instead of *for-loop*. I've tried the following code but I get an error message "*Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals*":

```
new_array=matrix(X,Y,Z);
```

I understand that Z is an array and cannot be put with X and Y which are integers. Is there a better way to create such array in one-liner code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
new_array=squeeze(matrix(X,Y,1:Z));
```

Comment: That's clear and clean! I've spent hours trying to understand _bsxfun_ and _arrayfun_ but _squeeze_... But I still wonder why `new_array=matrix(X,Y,Z)` doesn't work while the only difference in your code is the usage of _squeeze_ to flatten the new_array? I mean is there a problem in my indexing.

Comment: If you index any dimension beyond the second, you do not get a "normal" vector. Look at it yourself by displaying `matrix(X,Y,1:10)`. Actually, I had lots of trouble too before I stumbled upon squeeze.

Comment: Apparently, using _squeeze_ is much slower than a straight _for_ loop !!! I'm on **Matlab 2012a**. I've read a lot about the improvement in _for_ loops performance . It appears like my code gets worse in term of running time with every vectorization step. Maybe because of functions like _find_, _sum_ or _squeeze_ as I want to avoid any _for_ loops.

Comment: On my system with Matlab 2009a, the squeeze version takes about a third of the time the loop version takes.